# Is it correct to use being + V3 without to be in this case?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

Is it correct to use being+V3 form without "to be" in the following case?

After code being scanned, you will receive text

Comment: No, it's not correct. It's ungrammatical, and it's also incomprehensible out of context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After the code has been scanned you will receive a confirmation text.

Comment: To be perfectly correct, it ought to be:  After the code has been scanned a confirmation text will be sent.  Because that's all that can be done on that end.  Whether the text gets lost in transit or fails to get delivered is outside of your control.